# Bootstrap X-editable - use div, ajax or function to load custom type editor?

Tags: ajax, twitter-bootstrap-3, editor, x-editable

I'm using Bootstrap 3 with X-editable ( http://vitalets.github.io/bootstrap-editable/ )

I require a variety of custom type editors. It's impractical to implement them as string templates as indicated in the sample code:

```
         callOrQuoteEditor.defaults = $.extend({}, $.fn.editabletypes.abstractinput.defaults, {
             tpl: '<div class="editable-callorquote" >' +
                     '<label style="display:block; minWidth:180px">' +
                     '<select class="form-control input-sm" name="CallOrQuoteMode">' +
                     '  <option value="@CallOrQuoteMode.Call">call</option>' +
                     '  <option value="@CallOrQuoteMode.Quote">quote</option>' +
                     '</select>' +
                     ' within ' +
                     '<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="CallOrQuoteValue" size="3">' +
                     '<select class="form-control input-sm" name="CallOrQuoteUnit">' +
                     '  <option value="@CallOrQuoteUnit.Minutes">minute(s)</option>' +
                     '  <option value="@CallOrQuoteUnit.Hours">hour(s)</option>' +
                     '  <option value="@CallOrQuoteUnit.Days">day(s)</option>' +
                    '</select>' +
                    '</label>' +
                 '</div>',

            inputclass: ''
        });
```

Rather I would like to do one of the following:

1) Load the template using an AJAX loaded form

2) Load the template from an existing, hidden

3) Load the template from a function call, from which I can return whatever I like

I cannot find any way in the documentation or sample code to do this.

Short of hacking bootstrap-editable.js script, what can I do?

Comment: Don't know bootstrap much but if the $ is jQuery can't you simply hide it in your HTML and use something like tpl: $("#myTemplate").html(), if the code run after dom ready of course.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: gillesc i will try that, it might just work.